# Duplicated Back-To-Top Button

Tags: php, html, css

One of my websites, [www.makememodern.com](http://makememodern.com), is displaying duplicate Back-To-Top buttons on all browsers when it should be showing one.

footer.php

```
<div id="back-to-top"><a href="#">Back to Top</a></div>
```

CSS

```
#back-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    display: none;
}
#back-to-top a {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #E45323 url(http://makememodern.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/backtotop.png) no-repeat center center;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s all linear;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s all linear;
    -o-transition: 0.2s all linear;
    transition: 0.2s all linear
}
#back-to-top a:hover {
    background-color: #222222;
}
```

HTML shows:

```
<div id="back-to-top" style="display: block;"><a href="&lt;/p"></a><a href="#">Back to Top</a></div>
```

I achieve my desired results when I erase `<a href="&lt;/p"></a>` from the HTML directly above, but I can't figure out how to change it permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a syntax error on line 790 in the view source.

```
<p>Copyright © 2014 Make Me Modern LLC, All rights reserved.   <a href=</p>
```

Looks like there might be an extraneous link tag `<a href=`
If for whatever reason the `<a href=` is intentional, then it needs to be completed.
The main thing is, you're missing a closing tag on that line.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Not sure why "<a href=" was there, but I removed it.

Comment: I think all you needed to do was fix that error and your double-image would have gone away.  You shouldn't have had to change your css.  I'm not sure what your JS is doing, but you could try putting your style back to the way it was and see if that fixes the button showing up right away when as user navigates to your page.

Comment: I reverted back to the original CSS after removing the extraneous link and it looks great. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is generating a different image for every `a` tag.
I suggest you to put the background image inside the #back-to-top style

```
#back-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    display: none;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #E45323 url(http://makememodern.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/backtotop.png) no-repeat center center;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s all linear;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s all linear;
    -o-transition: 0.2s all linear;
    transition: 0.2s all linear
}
#back-to-top a {
    display: block;
}
#back-to-top:hover {
    background-color: #222222;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. That was it. Any reason why it would be showing immediately on the homepage instead of appearing after scrolling down the page a little ways?

Comment: In my Opera/FF/Chrome (last versions) it doesn't appear on the homepage, it shows after some scroll.

Comment: Also, what Rylonian says is also correct, I do not understant the second `<a href`